# How to use a background task but i want it to send it using render to specific url

Tags: django, background-task

I try to render but it should put request using parameter, how to handle the request when using the background task in django

@background(schedule=60)  # Runs every 60 seconds
def auto_check_status (request):
current_time = timezone.now()
time_threshold = current_time - timedelta(minutes=10)

```
try:
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(
    Q(trx_status='PENDING') | Q(trx_status='SUBMITTED'),
    trx_type_id='R',
    trx_time__lt=time_threshold
).order_by('trx_time')

    for transaction in transactions:
        # Perform actions on each transaction
        store_database(transaction)
        message = createrequest(transaction)
        message = construct_source_string_and_sign(message)
        npg_url = f"{settings.NPG_URL}/in"
        npg_url = f"{settings.NPG_URL}/in"
        return render(request, 'transactions/bayar.html', {'trx': message, 'npg_url' :npg_url})

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```